# com6.log.asp, file with reserved word

Tags: windows, asp-classic, windows-server-2008-r2

A script kiddie has upload a shell on my website (IIS 7.5, Windows 2008R2). There are some files like **com7.log.asp** and **lpt5.log.asp** on one folder. This files use reserved words (lpt, com, prn). `Rm` (powershell) and `Del` (command line) can't delete this file (fuc... windows).

Do you known a way to delete this file (without reboot on a live linux distri) with ASP or another language?

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax to [DeleteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363915.aspx):

```
DeleteFileA("\\\\?\\c:\\repro\\com7.log.asp");
```

From the command line you use this syntax:

```
>del \\.\c:\repro\com7.log.asp
```

But you may want to flatten the box and reinstall everything.

Comment: Thanks. I have find another way "DirectoryFixer" [link](http://www.somacon.com/p132.php)